# How do I find out which groups I requested membership to?

Tags: facebook-groups

I have asked to join a Facebook group but it's been days and I got no reply. I'd like to contact the admins, or someone else who appears to be active in the place, to ask them if they can let me in (or if they don't want me).

The big problem is I can't find that group anymore - I deleted my cache for a different reason and I can't get the name out of my memory.

Is there a way to see which groups I've been asking to join?